# Can't ship log from local server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'have a problem related to logstash and elasticsearch.

When I try to ship logs via logstash from a remote machine to my elasticsearch server, no problem, index are created.
But when I try to ship logs via logstash from the server that is hosting elasticsearch, no index are created, nothing happens.

Logging from logstash shows that logstash sees whitout problem the logs I'm trying to ship.

I can't figure out why this is happening.
Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

ES version : 1.0.1
Logstash version : 1.4.0

logstash config file :

```
input { 
      file {
    type => "dmprocess"
    path => "/logs/mysql.log*"
  }    
}

filter{



    grok{
        type => "dmprocess"
        match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:processTimeStamp} %{GREEDYDATA} Extraction done for %{WORD:alias} took %{NUMBER:milliseconds:int} ms for %{NUMBER:rows:int} rows",
                   "message", "%{DATESTAMP:processTimeStamp} %{GREEDYDATA} : %{GREEDYDATA} %{WORD:alias} took %{NUMBER:milliseconds:int} ms"]
    }

        date{
        match => [ "processTimeStamp", "YY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]

    }



}

output { 

    elasticsearch { 
    host=>"devmonxde"
    cluster => "devcluster"

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** 
It seems that I'am not able to ship logs via input:file to an elasticsearch instance(remote or local) from a linux host.
Though I am able to send data to ES via input:stdin. So no connection/port problem.

It works like a charm if I run logstash with same config, but from a windows host.

The default behaviour on windows seems to be "beginning". This look in contradiction with the doc http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/file#start_position

It seems that logstash does not import old logs, even with start_position="beginning" of the file input.

The problem is that my old log are not imported into ES.
I'am creating another post for this.
Thanks
[Old logs are not imported into ES by logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631906/old-logs-are-not-imported-into-es-by-logstash)

Comment: The problem is that my old log are not imported into ES.
I'am creating another post for this.
Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631906/old-logs-are-not-imported-into-es-by-logstash

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to change the host to localhost, 127.0.0.1 or the external ip address to make sure the host name is not the problem.

Another thing would be to add an output to log everything to the console, easy way to check if the messages are coming in and are parsed the right way.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your suggestions. I've tried with the 127.0.0.1 and external IP, it did not fix the problem. I've added a stdin input, and when I type something into the console, the new index is created.

Comment: Ok, so the problem must be with the input as specified in input config. Is the path: /logs/mysql.log* correct? Why do you use the wildcard after mysql, is there log rotation? Are new lines appended to the log? A lot of questions, hope one of them helps.

Comment: Yes there is a log rotation. The path is also correct. Also logstash logging shows that the files are discovered. (glob_discovered ...). I've tried to run both ES and logstash as root to eliminate enventual privileges problems but it didn't help. Could it be a conflict between logstash integrated ES client and my ES instance ?

Comment: It is possible but I would expect an error than. But you said that adding the command line input you could send messages to elasticsearch. That is was surprises me. You are using 1.4 of logstash, that should use elasticsearch 1.0.1. Maybe switch to the http client? This is new in 1.4. Do not know the format by head.