# Old logs are not imported into ES by logstash

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash

When I start logstash, the old logs are not imported into ES.
Only the new request logs are recorded in ES.
Now I've see this in the [doc](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/file#start_position).

Even if I set the `start_position=>"beginning"`, old logs are not inserted.
This only happens when I run logstash on linux.

If I run it with the same config, old logs are imported.
I don't even need to set `start_position=>"beginning"` on windows.

Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read an input log to Logstash, Logstash will keep an record about the position it read on this file, that's call [sincedb](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/file#sincedb_path).

```
Where to write the sincedb database (keeps track of the current position of monitored log files). 
The default will write sincedb files to some path matching "$HOME/.sincedb*"
```

So, if you want to import old log files, you must delete all the .sincedb* at your $HOME.
Then, you need to set

> start_position=>"beginning"

at your configuration file.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This is it. The problem has been fixed by setting a value for the sincedb_path. So the sincedb was recreated at first startup. The problem could also be fixed by deleting the orginal  $HOME/.sincedb*. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see this line also.

*This option only modifies "first contact" situations where a file is new and not seen before. If a file has already been seen before, this option has no effect.*